# Cannot run C# in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I downloaded Visual Studio Code and Intellisense extension for C#. I wrote my code, but when I pressed F5 (Start Debugging) to run the code using "Net", It didn't do anything. I tried to use "Net Core", but It only "redirects" me to a file called settings.json, how do I fix my problem?

Comment: Does [Working with C#: Common questions](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/csharp#_common-questions) help?

Comment: Is there [anything logged in the Terminal tab](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/debugging-with-visual-studio-code#start-debugging) ?

Comment: Have you checked this page?
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/csharp